# How can I join two tables when the join columns have different names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have these two tables and I need to create a report of `PhraseId` and `English` where the `UserName` is `'admin1'`.

The `ModifiedBy` column matches up with the `Id` column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PhrasePhraseChapter] FOREIGN KEY ([ChapterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PhraseChapter] ([PhraseChapterShortId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

How can I join these two tables when the join columns have different names?

Comment: the same as if the column names were identical

Comment: The bigger question is _which_ two columns from these tables would be used in doing the join.  It's not clear to me from a quick glance what the answer to that question is.

Comment: Having different names doesn't change anything. As long as the tables are related to each other then join those related columns.

Comment: @Lamak Cheeky comment, but not really constructive

Comment: @Bruno9779 Lamak's comment is the correct answer.

Comment: @Bruno9779 I believe it is. There is no requirement in SQL Server that joining columns be named identically, so the response is completely valid. The question seems to assume that the columns must be named the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Op has stated: `ModifiedBy matches up with Id`

Comment: @Bruno9779 Why not?, now op can search how to perform a `JOIN` and use that to answer his/her question

Comment: Given the nature of the question I think what the OP needs is some training.

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/75773/

Comment: One thing I would caution you with here is that since you are storing the Id in the ModifiedBy column you will lose that history when a user is deleted.

Comment: @Lamak, if you had commented to OP to look up how to join columns with different names, that would have been helpful. What you commented is only very slightly more helpful than saying " .... the right way ...."

Comment: @Lamak I guess you are right, but apparently OP cannot JOIN at all, so ...

Comment: @CharlesBretana "let me google this for you" aren't welcomed comments. And my comment actually had information behind it. You can join them the same way that you could if the names were the same

Comment: @Option Sorry...it helps to read the question :-)

Comment: @Lamak,  next time, put the information in front of it instead of behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the column names in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.[PhraseId], p.[English]
FROM   [dbo].[Phrase] p
JOIN   [dbo].[AspNetUsers] a ON p.[ModifiedBy] = a.[Id]
WHERE  a.[UserName] = 'admin'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by left joining the `AspNetUsers` to the `Phrase` table.  This will allow all users to appear in the report, even if they have no matching phrase information.  Note that `COALESCE()` is used to appropriately handle missing information for a given user, should that occur.  In this case, we are targeting a specific user, but this approach will at least result in a single record showing up in the result set should the phrase information be missing.

```
SELECT t1.[Id],
       t1.[UserName],
       COALESCE(t2.[PhraseId], -1) AS PhraseId,
       COALESCE(t2.[English], 'NA') AS English
FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Phrase] t2
    ON t1.[Id] = t2.[ModifiedBy]
WHERE t1.[UserName] = 'admin1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any column names for joining (if it has sense). Usually, it is primary key for master table, and foreign key for detail table, wgich corresponds to master:

```
select * from
Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where t1.id=t2.ref_id
```

But which columns you wanna use for join these two tables?